# replicate namespace and root element attributes with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml

Trying to replicate the following root element including namespace:

```
<ns0:StdFX1.3 xmlns:ns0="http://website.com/schemas/StdFX1.3.In" 
CutOff="2200LON" DataSource="" SpotDataSource="">

</ns0:StdFX1.3>
```

here is my code so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace("", "http://website.com/schemas/StdFX1.3.In")
top = ET.Element('{http://website.com/schemas/StdFX1.3.In}Stuff')
```

it only gets me the following though:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
< xmlns="http://website.com/schemas/StdFX1.3.In">
```

Comment: You already registered the empty namespace prefix, so you shouldn't need to provide the URI in the `Element` constructor call.  I.e. `top = ET.Element('Stuff')`. Not an answer as it's been years since I used Python.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and used string substitution on the final object.

```
root.tostring().replace("mangled toplevel namespace", '<ns0:StdFX1.3 xmlns:ns0="http://website.com/schemas/StdFX1.3.In" 
    CutOff="2200LON" DataSource="" SpotDataSource="">')
```

Likewise for the closing tag. Any other way just wouldn't keep the changes I specified.

`fromString` method to get back to the element tree. I was just submitting XML so didn't so I can't remember if this effected your desired changes, but you get the desired XML.